# If $A=[0, 1] \times (0, 1)$, which is a subspace of $I^2 = [0, 1] \times [0, 1],$ how are the sets $U_x = \{x\} \times (0, 1)$ open in $A$?

Tags: general-topology

If each of $U_x$ is open, doesn't this imply that $\{x\}$ is open in $[0, 1]$, which contradicts the uncountability of $[0, 1]$?

This question arises from an example (#5) in James Munkres' Topology, pg. 193.

Comment: openess of singleton and countability has nothing to do one to each other: you can put on any set the discrete topology for which every set is open. A part of that, what exactly is your question?

Comment: If $A$ is equipped with the standard (euclidian) topology, then $\{x\}\times (0,1)$ is not open in $A$. It is, in fact, closed in $A$.

Comment: In the standard topology $U_x$ is never open for any $x$ because any open ball intersection $U_x$ must also intersect $A\setminus U_x$.

Comment: I was just confused by the exact same page of Munkres and fortunately found this explanation. Thanks!

Comment: fyi, Munkres does the same thing earlier on page 90, where he says that $\{1/2\} \times (1/2,1]$ is open in $I \times I$ in the subspace topology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that this example does not deal with the usual product $I \times I = I^2$, but with the [(lexicographically) ordered square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order_topology_on_the_unit_square), which Munkres denotes by $I_{\text{o}}^2$.  The topology here is generated by the family of all "open intervals" $$( \mathbf{a} , \mathbf{b} ) := \{ \mathbf{x} \in I\times I : \mathbf{a} <_{\text{lex}} \mathbf{x} <_{\text{lex}} \mathbf{b} \}$$ where $\mathbf{a} <_{\text{lex}} \mathbf{b}$ belong to $I \times I$. ($<_{\text{lex}}$ is the usual lexicographic order on $I \times I$.)

In this case, the sets $U_x := \{ x \} \times (0,1)$ are just equal to the "open interval" $(\,\langle x,0 \rangle , \langle x,1 \rangle\,)$, and are thus open (since they are "open intervals").